# Gradle: remove warning "Ivy.xml dependency overrides are not supported by Gradle. Ignoring override declared in file ..."

Tags: logging, gradle, ivy

we're using gradle and sometimes we need to use the --debug option ... mostly to debug :)

Sadly it always starts with 1000th of line similar to the following:

```
10:47:59.963 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.IvyXmlModuleDescriptorParser] Ivy.xml dependency overrides are not supported by Gradle. Ignoring override declared in file:/home/theUser/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/module-metadata/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream/1.4.3/eebae40ade9db71730f76b773ea495c/ivy.xml
```

It seems that all of them are caused by some third party libs.

How is it possible avoid these lines? Ether by fixing the problem or just by filtering the logs.

It would be great if the solution inside gradle because we currently use '*gradle | grep -iv ivy*' which is very unhandy.

Comment: There's not much you can do on the Gradle side, except perhaps to try with a newer Gradle version, which may log different debug messages.